# How to isolate $x$ in $k(1-q)c e^{-kx}- aqe^{-ax}+ qe^{-kx - ax} (k + a)-kqce^{-kx}=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been working on a problem for which I wish to characterize the maximum of a function $f(x)$. As a result, I calculated its derivative, shown below, and made it equal to zero. Several days later, I still haven't figured out the best way to isole $x$ on the equation below (note that $x$ is only in the exponents). Naturally, a trivial solution exists where $x\rightarrow\infty$, but I'm interested in the finite solution. If anyone could shed a light, that would be greatly appreciated!

I.e., I'm looking for a clever way to isolate $x$ in the equation below:

$$k(1-q)c e^{-kx}- aqe^{-ax}+ qe^{-kx - ax} (k + a)-kqce^{-kx}=0$$

Comment: Why do you format the equation so strangely? Is that intentional?

Comment: Why not just state the original problem? Often, trying to ask for help from an intermediate step is like asking someone to finish your half-eaten meal - it ain't pretty, it's often a mess, and the other person would probably enjoy the experience more stating afresh.

Comment: Perhaps define a new variable $y = e^{k x}$ and solve for $y$.

Comment: Just to show how to typeset:  $$k (1-q) c e^{-kx} - a q e^{-k x} + q (k+a) e^{-k x - a x} - k q c e^{-k x} = 0$$

Comment: Thanks! My issue with defining $y=e^{-kx}$ is that $e^{-ax}$ also exists

Comment: Sure.  But factor out the $e^{-k x}$ from the whole equation.  That gives you one solution.  Then look at the other factor and set it to zero to find other solutions.

Comment: Thanks! There's a small issue with the typeset you included - the second $e^{-kx}$ is actually $e^{-ax}$ (see question for the correct equation). This is why I'm having difficulties factoring out the $e^{-kx}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some algebra manipulation, your equation is equivalent to:

$$e^{- ax} (k + a)- ae^{(k-a)x}=kc\frac{2q-1}{q}$$

which is equivalent to:

$$Ay +By^{b}=C$$

where $y=e^{-ax}$, $b=1-k/a$, and $A,B,C$ are placeholder constants/parameters. In general depending on the value of $b$, there is no simple way to isolate $y$. (So no simple way to isolate $x$.)

Of course for some values of $b$, it's easy. Like if $b=-1$, $0$, $\frac12$, $1$, or $2$.